# html форма в балуне "Яндекс карт" с использованием Timepicker для ввода форматированного времени

Tags: javascript, php, html, form, yandex-maps-api

Я делаю сайт на NetCatу, где необходима яндекс карта, но не простая - при щелчке по карте должен всплывать балун с формой, куда вноситься информация, среди которой должна быть строчка ввода времени формата чч:мм:сс.

Карту и открывающийся балун я сделал, благо на сайте яндекса есть примеры, форму тоже туда засунул, но когда я решил подключить туда jQuery плагин [Timepicker Addon 0.5](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/), то возникла проблема - этот плагин не хочет работать внутри скрипта карты. Хотя если просто использовать его на странице компонента, то все работает. Обращаюсь к вам за помощью.

Вот код моей карты с формой и попыткой подключения плагина:

```
        // Как только будет загружен API и готов DOM, выполняем инициализацию
        ymaps.ready(init);

        function init () {
            var myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
                    center: [55.790833, 49.114444], // Красное-на-Волге
                    zoom: 11
                }, {
                    balloonMaxWidth: 250
                });

            // Обработка события, возникающего при щелчке
            // левой кнопкой мыши в любой точке карты.
            // При возникновении такого события откроем балун.
            myMap.events.add('click', function (e) {
                if (!myMap.balloon.isOpen()) {
                    var coords = e.get('coordPosition');
                    myMap.balloon.open(coords, {
                        contentHeader: 'Новая контрольная зона',
                        contentBody: '<form id=formadd action=/template/control_zones/outpoint.php method=post target=_self>'+
                                'Устройство к которому будет добавлена контрольная зона :'+
                                ' ";
                    $res_devicesList = mysql_query(" SELECT * FROM `siteonfly_tracker`.`Message113` WHERE `User_ID` = '$current_user[User_ID]' ");
                    $result .='<select name="deviceID" size="1" >';
                    while($list = mysql_fetch_assoc($res_devicesList)) {
                        $result .= '<option value="'.$list[DeviceID].'">'.$list['Name'].' '.$list[DeviceID].'</option>';//Device_ID
                    }
                    $result .= '</select>';
                    $res_phone = mysql_query(" SELECT `Phone` FROM `siteonfly_tracker`.`User` WHERE `User_ID` = '$current_user[User_ID]' ");
                    $phone_sel = mysql_fetch_assoc($res_phone);
                        $phone = $phone_sel['Phone'];
                    $result.=" '+
                                'Название :<input type=text name=namepoint><br>'+
                                'Радиус :<input type=text name=radiuspoint><br>'+
                                ' ";
                    $result .='<input type="text" name="testTime" style="width: 70px;" id="timepickerTestInMap" value="" />';

                    //$result .='<script type="text/javascript">';
                    $result .='            $(document).ready(function() {';
                    $result .='                $("#timepickerTestInMap").timepicker();';
                    $result .='            });';
                    //$result .='        </script>';
                    $result .=" '+
                                ' ";
                                $result .= 'Время начала контроля (чч:мм:сс) :<input type="text" name="begintime" style="width: 70px;" id="timepickerBegin" value="">';
                                $result.=" '+
                                ' ";
                                $result .= '<br>Время окончания контроля (чч:мм:сс) :<input type="text" name="endtime" style="width: 70px;" id="timepickerEnd" value="">';
                                $result.=" '+
                                '<input type=submit name=submit_cz >'+
                                '<input name=pcoord type=hidden value='+coords[0].toPrecision(6)+';'+coords[1].toPrecision(6)+' />'+
                                '<input name=phone type=hidden value=$phone />'+
                                '</form>',
                        contentFooter: '<p>Координаты контрольной зоны: ' + [
                                coords[0].toPrecision(6),
                                coords[1].toPrecision(6)
                            ].join(', ') + '</p>'
                    });
                } else {
                    myMap.balloon.close();
                }
            });

            // Обработка события, возникающего при щелчке
            // правой кнопки мыши в любой точке карты.
            // При возникновении такого события покажем всплывающую подсказку.
            myMap.events.add('contextmenu', function (e) {
                myMap.hint.show(e.get('coordPosition'), 'Кто-то щелкнул правой кнопкой');
            });
            //управление картой
            myMap.behaviors.enable('scrollZoom')
        // Добавление стандартного набора кнопок
        myMap.controls.add('mapTools')
        // Добавление кнопки изменения масштаба 
        .add('zoomControl')
        // Добавление списка типов карты
        .add('typeSelector');
        }
```

как видите я сначала пытался засунуть скрипт в скрипт, но тогда при встречи внутреннего `</script>` закрывался и внешний скрипт карты, так что это место я закомментировал, но теперь код вызова функции плагина вылезает наружу страницы.

P.S. для тех, кто не знает - в `NetCat php` код вставляется с помощью такой конструкции `"; *[php код]* $result.="`, где все

```
`echo '';`
```

надо заменить на

`>$result.='';`

Answer (score 1):

```
 $result .='<script>';
                    $result .='            $(document).ready(function() {';
                    $result .='                $("#timepickerTestInMap").timepicker();';
                    $result .='            });';
                    $result .='        </script>';
```

попробуйте без типа javascript у меня так работал

Comment: угараю=)))

Comment: @Palmervan вы на его предыдущие ответы посмотрите. Там в одном из них человек не просил минусовать данного товарища за его неопытность еще в апреле месяце того года. Это также весело, как смотреть видео-обзоры от Мишы Табуреткина :D

Comment: @lampa да я только за сегодня навеселился)

Comment: не помогло(

Comment: @lampa а я ещё его вопрос про DOM (сначала) просил не минусовать :)